# Run kafka producer with a fixed/static list of brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

Usually the kafka java client (used within Spring boot, but that does not really matter here, I think, just as a side node) uses the `boostrap.servers` config (which expects a list of broker addresses:port) to establish an initial connection. Afterwards, a metadata request is used to discover all members of the cluster, which are currently registered.

My question now is, how this discovery can be disabled in the java client. I want to have the `KafkaProducer` use the list of brokers I supply to it as a fixed, static one.

#### A little bit more background

The platform my Spring application is deployed to, does not allow internet access to any port, except when using an HTTP proxy (443 or 80). The other alternative is to use a TCP proxy, which works similar to this:

- The proxy provides a hostname and port an application can connect to
- Once connected, the data stream is forwarded to the previously (during the creation of the proxy) named hostname and port

In that way, the platform can control what traffic is coming from who and is going where, which is a security requirement in my organisation. The communication path then looks like:

```
----------------------         -------------         -----------------------
| Application client |  <--->  | TCP Proxy |  <--->  | Target (e.g. kafka) |
----------------------         -------------         -----------------------
```

However, this method does not really work with the public kafka cluster I need to talk to, as the kafka broker in the boostrap.servers list (which I can connect to perfectly fine) will return the list of nodes with the public endpoint names I can not connect to (as they're not going through the proxy).

So, instead of using the discovery functionality of the Kafka client, I would like to use a fixed, pre-defined list of brokers, which I can setup to use the TCP proxy. However, I didn't see any solution for that in the API so far and hope for some help here.

I'm aware, that not using this functionality makes it impossible for the application to use the dynamic changes of the kafka cluster state (when a broker goes away and another one is spinned up), however, this is ok in my scenario and all given circumstances.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it's more complicated than that - I think the client needs to talk directly to the broker instance where a partition resides (it gets that information from the metadata).

Comment: Maybe something I forget to add: As the kafka cluster is maintained inside of the organisation, I know all brokers of the cluster beforehand (at least their DNS names) and can create the TCP proxy instances beforehand. So, it's probably not disabling the whole discovery, "just" the nodes part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does not allow internet access to any port, **except when using an HTTP proxy (443 or 80).**

Have you considered using the [Confluent REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html)?

> The Confluent REST Proxy provides a RESTful interface to a Kafka cluster, making it easy to produce and consume messages, view the state of the cluster, and perform administrative actions without using the native Kafka protocol or clients

Maven coords for a Client

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-rest</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

There is also an envoy proxy solution in the works - https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2852

And another TCP proxy for k8s environments - https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy

However, exposing NodePorts / headless service ports would be the correct way to expose a k8s kafka cluster

Comment: Alright, this was also something I'm checking, if we can enable this in the kafka cluster I want to use. However, your comment on another question about the kafka proxy looks promising (https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy) without having this RES proxy as well. As this answer and your comment brings me way closer to a suitable solution, I'm keen to mark it as the answer. Would you just write the kafka-proxy idea into your answer as well, so future readers see it as well? :)

Answer (score 0):

While there is not a way to *not use Metadata requests*, you might consider the `advertised.listeners` config, which will let your internal-network brokers advertise the hostname and port you have configured on the proxy for that particular broker, in responses to the Metadata request.

More details can be found [here](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear from my question, but the kafka brokers are not "internally", so this is not about changing the brokers configuration, at least as I understand the advertised.listeners property. The returned hostnames are totally fine and correct from the point of view of the broker. The problem here is, that I can not reach them without the TCP proxy.

Comment: Suppose your broker can be reached by other brokers at `mybroker1:9092`.   Then suppose you set up a proxy for this broker so that external calls to `myproxy:1234` forward to `mybroker1:9092`.  You would add an `advertised.listener` of `myproxy:1234` to your broker, so that when the client requests the list of brokers and partition assignments with a `MetadataRequest`, the response will say that `myproxy:1234` is a valid address of it, so their communications will be forwarded by the proxy to `mybroker1:9092`

Comment: That was one of my ideas already (didnt mention that in the question, as I thought this is a dirty solution). However, it even didn't work. I'll update the question with the code, if I still have it (maybe on monday, maybe earlier). Could you add some code on how to do that to your answer? Maybe even with an embedded kafka broker for testing?

Comment: Cool -- as for code, there is no code change needed, just setting an additional `advertised.listener` on each broker which reflects the proxy host and proxy port set up for that broker.  The link in the answer gives example configs to do what it appears you are trying to do

Comment: no, wait. That, then, will not work, if I need to change advertised listeners on the broker. They can not be changed to the tcp proxy ones for several reasons, so that's, at the moment, not an option. What I tried (and mentioned in my last comment) was to start an in-memory kafka broker, which advertised the host of the TCP proxy. This, however, didn't really work out.

Comment: What are the several reasons?

Comment: The probably most important ones are: The TCP proxy I need to use is application specific, so each app (where app means "a product", which can consist out of multiple application) needs to have it's own one. And putting in the multiple various possible tcp proxy instances into the broker list doesn't sounds feasible.

Comment: Since my answer resolves your question, and you cannot apply it only because your organization chooses to require a separate proxy listener for each Kafka client (not technically necessary, but rather politically required in your org, as client differentiation can be done broker-side), and you personally do not want to set up a listener for each client as required by the politics of your organization, would you mind marking my response as answering the question, please?

Comment: Why can't TCP proxies be used? Ref https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2852 & https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to directly connecting to each broker on its advertised hostname, which is necessary for the functionality of Kafka, you might also consider setting up 1 or more [Kafka REST proxies](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html) within your network, and then either pointing the proxy to that, or pointing the proxy to a load-balancer which balances across multiple Kafka REST proxies.

Comment: This is actually a separate, "alternative" answer, unrelated to the other one :)  EDIT: I see you have now proposed a similar solution -- great minds think alike! :)